# Is there a need for mutual Authentication in the following use case? if so why?

Tags: authentication, mutual

I came across this use case where mobile devices operating in a pull architecture (connecting to an AWS cloud service endpoint) based on some device triggers will request to be unlocked via a TLS connection. The response will just send a signed message containing the password (to generate a password hash) which will only work on that specific device. I am not worried about the password leaking as the data will be signed by my private key and all the devices will have the pub key. Additionally, replaying the message is not a concern either as this only happens one time after a certain duration. The cloud service determines when to unlock the device. Am I missing anything?

1. Device app sends a request to an aws service for unlocking along with a unique
   identifier UID.
2. Aws Service uses that UID to do a lookup up of the correct passcode and constructs appropriate signed payload containing the passcode
3. The service then sends it to the device app for processing.
4. The device app returns a success or failure after the operation is complete.

Comment: Mutual TLS is needed when TLS level authentication of the client is necessary. From your description I cannot conclude that this is the case, but I cannot determine either that this should not be the case since there might be missing details.

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for responding. I really appreciate you. What would change the calculus in your estimation for this scenario? I am not sending anything back to the service other than an ack or nack. That’s it. The service just has one purpose and it is to unlock the device nothing more or less.

Comment: *" I am not sending anything back to the service other than an ack or nack."* - this does not match your question which states *"The response will just send a signed message containing the password (to generate a password hash) which will only work on that specific device"*

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say after all said and done the client just responds with a success or failure after processing the response payload that has the signed payload containing the passcode.Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain in your question in a more formal way, what exact data gets send in the request and what is send back in the response. I find the current explanation including the comments too confusing.

Comment: Adjusted the main question with a flow for clarity